# Can I specify graphene object types as arguments for a graphene mutations?

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-django

I'm mapping Django models to GraphQL API with `graphene_django`. The models reference each other with one-to-many and many-to-many relations. For "create" GraphQL mutations which shall create instances of models without relation references you simply use the model field as mutation arguments.

However for "create" GraphQL mutations which shall create instances for models which have "child" models (model instances which are referenced via a relationship) it would be advanterous to beeing able to pass the one/several "child" model/s as corresponding Graphene object types (classes which inherit from `DjangoObjectType`) as mutation arguments. I've not found any tutorial/design guide which shows how to do that yet. How could I achieve this?